# flask-marshmallow - how to conditionally generate HATEOAS URLS

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to selectively return some urls based on the current state of the object and am having a heck of a time solving how to expose the state property in the Schema, do some logic and determine which URLs to return based on the object state:

The Model:

```
class Car(Model):
    model = Column(String)
    year = Column(String)
    running = Column(Boolean)   #'0 = not running', '1 = running'
```

and the schema:

```
class CarSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('model', 'year', 'running',  '_links')

    _links = ma.Hyperlinks({
        'self': ma.URLFor('car_detail', id='<id>'),
        'start': ma.URLFor('car_start', id='<id>')
        'stop': ma.URLFor('car_start', id='<id>')
    })
```

What i'd like to do is have the start url only returned when the 'running' property is 0, and the stop url returned when it's 1, but i'm unclear on how to accomplish this.

Marshmallow seems to have a few decorators that would seem to but how would I leverage them with flask-marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with post_dump post-processing: check running status and remove inappropriate fields. That'll be much easier than generating them conditionally.

```
class CarSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('model', 'year', 'running', '_links')

    _links = ma.Hyperlinks({
        'self': ma.URLFor('car_detail', id='<id>'),
        'start': ma.URLFor('car_start', id='<id>')
        'stop': ma.URLFor('car_start', id='<id>')
    })

    @ma.post_dump
    def postprocess(self, data):
        if data['running']:
            del data['_links']['start']
        else:
            del data['_links']['stop']
```